# how to change login in windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I hosted an application in my IIS with Windows Authentication.

So, I logged to system with Login: 'William' and when i open application first time it asks authentication then i entered details of other authentic user say 'John'. Now, i want use that application with 'William' log in but it doesn't ask me for authentication(as i entered first time).

I have enabled Windows Authentication in IIS and set authentication mode to Windows in config file of application.

```
  <authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need [impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/134ec8tc(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: no, i want to use application with William login as i am logged in to Machine with William login. I want to know how it will again ask me my credential.

Comment: That's exactly what Windows Authentication is - it uses the currently logged in user to authenticate against the site.

Comment: @James but my application shows John as logged in user

Comment: Show the code that displays the text?

Comment: Unless you have asked your web browser to save the credentials, you should be able to log in as another. Thus, try to clear your browser cache, and then restart the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows Authentification is set up, your code can directly use it without any login/password prompt.

If you need to change into another user, you can use impersonnation

```
using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" ) )
{
...   
code to executes under the new context  
...
}
```